# I can neither add new contact to Google account nor sync contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account

My ASUS ZE554KL (Android 8.0) lost its ability to sync contacts. And when I add a new contact it offers to sync with: device, SIM and that's it. Below there was a list of my Google accounts, but now there's only "Add account" as if I don't have any.

upd. Added new Google account to the device, then tried to add new contaсts, no change in the end.

Comment: Could you search for "sync" inside Android Settings? There may be "Google Contacts sync" related to Google Play Services, or otherwise "Password & accounts" to check the sync status of your Google account.

Comment: @AndrewT. sync is turned on, it works for calendar, gmail, tasks etc. Ant there is an arrow icon with an exclamation mark in front of the contacts. And "Sunc is currently experiencing problems ..." at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

It might be because Google no longer supports Android 8.0 Oreo, according to [Lifewire Android Version Guide](https://www.lifewire.com/android-versions-4173277)

Comment: "Google is now letting you use its Contacts app on any Android phone"
https://mashable.com/article/google-contacts-is-available-on-any-android-device
Looks like there is some other cause of my issue

Comment: The statement "Google no longer supports Android 8.0 Oreo" is more about providing security patch updates, not really about sync though. My Nexus 5 on Android 7.1.2 still syncs Google contacts properly.